# What should be our chat feed bots avatars?

Tags: discussion

As you maybe know it, our site have a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52824/the-greenhouse) where we can talk together.

This chat room has feed bots that publish new main and meta questions in the discussion. These bots can have their avatar customized.

That's where **we want you**! As this room is the one of our community, **don't hesitate to propose and/or vote you preferred avatars**!

The names of our bots are **The Farmer** (posts new main site questions) and **The Gardener** (posts new meta questions).

*I suggest to post one avatar proposal per answer so that we can vote on it. Feel free to make several!*

Answer (score 5):

For now, default avatars have been set to easily distinguish them. Thank you Riker for that. :)

They're wearing respectively the main site and meta icon:

**The Farmer**
[image: Vegetarianism]

**The Gardener**
[image: Vegetarianism Meta]

### Vote on this post to keep these avatars.

Comment: Woah, tha'ts actually not the avatars. I used the 32*32px favicon icons, lol.  I'll edit these in later.

Comment: @Riker Many users, including me, got a bug with the favicons so I changed them to these images instead.

Comment: Ah, okay. That's perfectly fine with me.